# Remove the rows which contain double underscore in the column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a column name called Box which contains 4000+ rows with unique variable names.Every variable in the row differentiated by the first letter and the last number present in the string in a row. for example, A_B(1),A__B(1),C__D(3),D__F(2), AA__B(1).
Since, In this case, I want to remove all the rows which contains __ (double underscore) in the string.

Previous I have done with the based on the names. But I don't want to be hardcoded. I want to be generic. Just remove all the rows which contains double underscore(__).

```
#to_remove = ['I__ND_LD\(\d+\)', 'I__BS_ND\(\d+\)','I__LN_LN2\(\d+\)','P__ND_LN2\(\d+\)','I__XF_XF2\(\d+\)','P__ND_XF2\(\d+\)']
#eda=eda[~eda.Devices.str.contains('|'.join(to_remove), regex=True)]
```

Please let me know how we can use pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[~df['Box'].str.contains(r'_{2}')]
```

An example:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['James', 'Mary', 'John', 'Patricia'],
                    'B' : [30, 37, 30, 35], 
                    'C' : ['Robert', 'Jennifer', 'Michael', 'Linda'], 
                    'D' : ['Drop__A', 'Keep_A', 'Dr__pB', 'Keep_B']})

df1.loc[~df1['D'].str.contains(r'_{2}')]


          A   B         C       D
1      Mary  37  Jennifer  Keep_A
3  Patricia  35     Linda  Keep_B
```